# systemd fails to umount manually mounted NFS shares in initramfs

Tags: debian, systemd, mount, nfs

My **diskless** laboratory computers do not shutdown properly because `systemd` probably do not handle properly **manual** NFS mounts in `initramfs`. I'll describe shortly what is happening:

1. I created `initramfs` in which I mount `ro` several NFS shares (whole `/`, profiles, etc.) and overlay them using `overlayfs` to create `rw` Debian diskless for each workstation.
2. Then I `switch_root` to this overlayed system and it boots perfectly fine and works without problems. Homes are mounted separately during the boot based on `fstab`.
3. In my system I disabled Network Manager completely to prevent users from fiddling with network. This would be very harmful to them :)
4. When I'm doing shutdown system hangs with the `nfs: server not responding, still trying...` (this happens also with NM enabled, but in this case sometimes the shutdown succedes, but it is indeterministic).

So, my manual mount are "hidden" somehow from the `systemd` (I suspect that). My `fstab`:

```
none           /       overlay  defaults,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target 0 0
X.X.X.X:/home  /home   nfs      rw,nodev,nosuid,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,nfsvers=3,sec=krb5,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target    0   0
```

I tried `_netdev`, `x-systemd.requires...` but nothing helps.

Is there a solution for this? How can I umount all NFS shares under the overlayed `/` or at least forcibly reboot the system after `/home` is umounted properly? (system is diskless and all changes are in `overlayfs`, so it is safe to just, for example `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`) ;)

Best Regards
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

I spent two days and found somewhat reliable solution. I read half of the Internet and chatted on `#systemd` IRC. Please read this docs, maybe this will help you; for me, none of this helped, I couldn't make it work.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/InitrdInterface/
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/RootStorageDaemons/

I ended up overriding `systemd` services responsible for shutting down or rebooting a machine.

Create override directories:

- `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.service.d`
- `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-reboot.service.d`
- `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-halt.service.d`

And put inside `override.conf` files.
For `poweroff`:

```
[Unit]
SuccessAction=poweroff-immediate
```

For `reboot`:

```
[Unit]
SuccessAction=reboot-immediate
```

For `halt` (it is called for example, when Power Off button in Gnome is used):

```
[Unit]
ExecStart=systemctl --force --force halt
```

Adding a second `--force` or `immediate` does what it says. It does not wait for mounts or other things and just reboot/shutdown a machine. For NFS read-only mounts this is not harmful and can be done safely. Also, all changes from the `overlay` in my RAM will also be gone, which is fine. The `/home`, the only I care about will be umounted properly by the `home.mount` unit, created automatically for all `fstab` entries.

I hope that this will save someone two days of frustration ;)

Best Regards
Kamil